# Hide link value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Here is part of my mvc3 project code.

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.PolicyNo, "MasterView", new { PolicyNo = item.PolicyNo })
```

It will passing the "PolicyNo" to Controller, and the link bar will show this for example: 
"http://localhost:49237/Policy/Details1?PolicyNo=1001"

now my question is how to hide the value become :
"http://localhost:49237/Policy/Details1" only?

Comment: Do you have an action named Details1? Do you want to pass a default value for policyNo parameter?

Comment: Why does it matter if you can see the parameter or not?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I am aware of is to do a post request instead of a get.  In the post request, take the parameter 1001 and add it to session.

Then redirect the user to the action Details1.

Pull the value back out of the session and presto, the link bar will just show Details1.

HTH

Si